# Apache and Django: Invalid HTTP_HOST header

Tags: django, apache, configuration, host

We have Django application on Apache 2.4. We keep getting error: *Invalid* HTTP_HOST *header*. So we set Apache to allow only our host. Our urls are prov1.example.com, prov2.example.com ... Each url for specific provider.

```
<Directory '/project/wsgi'>
     Require host example.com
     Options -Indexes
</Directory>
```

But than we get error 403. We added `Satisfy Any` to allow access, but now we still getting *Invalid* HTTP_HOST *header*.

What have we set wrong?

Comment: Where exactly are you seeing the Invalid HTTP_HOST header error? Is it an Apache error in the web page returned? Is it in the Apache error log and generated by Apache? Or is it in a web page generated by Django if in DEBUG mode or appearing in the log file but still generated by Django?

Comment: Django return this error. We are geting a lot of mails (reporting error). This is on the production server. I was reading on stackoverflow that you need to block this request (with wrong header) with apache. So django doesn't get this kind of requests.